# Problem with Custom View for header in section not rendering on tap gesture UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift5, uitableviewsectionheader

I have tried n number of solutions, but still no luck. I designed my own Custom cell for Header of a Section. So my table renders properly.
Then for each header cell in func `viewForHeaderInSection()`, I've added tap gesture to handle click on header. But every time I click on any header it disappears from the table. I haven't written any code of deleting sections.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return ModelFacade.sharedInstanceModelFacade.getGenericModel().faqsArray.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AccordianHeaderPrototypeCell") as! AccordianHeaderPrototypeCell
        let cellinfo = ModelFacade.sharedInstanceModelFacade.getGenericModel().faqsArray[section]
        cell.headingLabel.text = cellinfo.title
        
        cell.arrowImage.tag = kHeaderSectionTag + section
        cell.arrowImage.image = Constants.DOWNARROW_IMAGE
        
        cell.tag = section
        let headerTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()
        headerTapGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.sectionHeaderWasTouched(_:)))
        cell.addGestureRecognizer(headerTapGesture)
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if (self.expandedSectionHeaderNumber == section) {
            return ModelFacade.sharedInstanceModelFacade.getGenericModel().faqsArray[section].contentArray.count
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProductDetailingsPrototypeCell", for: indexPath) as! ProductDetailingsPrototypeCell
        cell.separatorInset = .zero
        let cellinfo = ModelFacade.sharedInstanceModelFacade.getGenericModel().faqsArray[indexPath.section].contentArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.descriptionLabel.attributedText = cellinfo.html2Attributed
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
    
    @objc func sectionHeaderWasTouched(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let headerView = sender.view as! AccordianHeaderPrototypeCell
        let section = headerView.tag
        let eImageView = headerView.viewWithTag(kHeaderSectionTag + section) as? UIImageView
        if (self.expandedSectionHeaderNumber == -1) {
            self.expandedSectionHeaderNumber = section
            tableViewExpandSection(section, imageView: eImageView!)
        } else {
            if (self.expandedSectionHeaderNumber == section) {
                tableViewCollapeSection(section, imageView: eImageView!)
            } else {
                let cImageView = self.view.viewWithTag(kHeaderSectionTag + self.expandedSectionHeaderNumber) as? UIImageView
                tableViewCollapeSection(self.expandedSectionHeaderNumber, imageView: cImageView!)
                tableViewExpandSection(section, imageView: eImageView!)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func tableViewCollapeSection(_ section: Int, imageView: UIImageView) {
        let sectionData = ModelFacade.sharedInstanceModelFacade.getGenericModel().faqsArray[section].contentArray
        self.expandedSectionHeaderNumber = -1
        if (sectionData.count == 0) {
            return
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
                imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (0.0 * CGFloat(Double.pi)) / 180.0)
            })
            var indexesPath = [IndexPath]()
            for i in 0 ..< sectionData.count {
                let index = IndexPath(row: i, section: section)
                indexesPath.append(index)
            }
            self.itemsTableView!.beginUpdates()
            self.itemsTableView!.deleteRows(at: indexesPath, with: UITableView.RowAnimation.fade)
            self.itemsTableView!.endUpdates()
        }
    }
    
    func tableViewExpandSection(_ section: Int, imageView: UIImageView) {
        let sectionData = ModelFacade.sharedInstanceModelFacade.getGenericModel().faqsArray[section].contentArray
        if (sectionData.count == 0) {
            self.expandedSectionHeaderNumber = -1
            return
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
                imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (180.0 * CGFloat(Double.pi)) / 180.0)
            })
            var indexesPath = [IndexPath]()
            for i in 0 ..< sectionData.count {
                let index = IndexPath(row: i, section: section)
                indexesPath.append(index)
            }
            self.expandedSectionHeaderNumber = section
            self.itemsTableView.beginUpdates()
            self.itemsTableView.insertRows(at: indexesPath, with: UITableView.RowAnimation.fade)
            self.itemsTableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }
```

Adding two images to explain what happens before and after click.

[image: Before clicking on any header]

[image: After clicking on 3rd option]

Comment: hey can you check what's the value of `indexesPath` in the following line:      `self.itemsTableView!.deleteRows(at: indexesPath, with: UITableView.RowAnimation.fade)`

Comment: Instead of deletion and insertion, you could opt for just toggling the number of Rows in `numberOfRowsInSection`